# Bind a Label Font Size which is in an ASP.NET Gridview from a DataBase

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to bind a label's font-size from a database. The label is in a TemplateField. I have a column in my database with the name "FontSize" which contains data such as "small", "large", or "12px".

I used the below code to do this, but an error occurs. I think I might need to change my "FontSize" data format in the database or change the `Font-Size='<%# Eval("FontSize") %>'` line in the below code. How can I do this?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>    
            <asp:Label ID="Label3"  
                runat="server" 
                Font-Bold="True" 
                Text='<%# Eval("PubText") %>'
                Font-Size='<%# Eval("FontSize") %>'
                ForeColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("Color").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Not clear Error. I think it code should to be change, Like `ForeColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding a font size is kind of confusing because you can give it an explicit string value such as "12px" or "Smaller" like so:

```
Font-Size="12px"
```

But when you want to bind a value, it expects a [FontUnit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontunit(v=vs.110).aspx). Fortunately, FontUnit has a few methods that we can use to create the FontUnit we need from other datatypes. Since it looks like your data is strings, you probably need the [FontUnit.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd2kfxzt(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Font-Size='<%# FontUnit.Parse(Eval("FontSize").ToString()) %>'
```

There is also a [FontUnit.Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontunit.point(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes an integer. So you could use that if your data happened to be something like 10, 15, 20, etc.

```
Font-Size='<%# FontUnit.Point(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("FontSize"))) %>'
```

Comment: I used the second one. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask something. Is there any source to learn how to use this biding method? I mean when we use Eval to bind Data in a gridview. For example conditional statements or other new problems.

Comment: Microsoft's [ASP.NET data binding overview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307860) is actually pretty good. In my experience however, I've found that doing more complex logic, such as conditionals, is much easier in the code behind. In your case with a GridView, the [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event specifically.